# "Failed to execute default File Manager" error when opening the trash folder

Tags: filemanager, trash

When I click on trash icon, I get this error message:

> "Failed to execute default File Manager: Failed to execute child
>   process "run"(No such file or directory).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: does clicking on the folder icon in the top left work? also, the "boot failure" tag is wrong

Comment: even icon disk I got same error.please I need assistance.I can't upload picture in this conversation because there's so many term to do.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/355848/how-do-i-reset-to-the-default-file-manager-for-all-folders

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-install the file manager i am going to assume you are using the default manager nautilus.

sudo apt-get remove nautilus

This will un-install then you can re-install with

sudo apt-get install nautilus

Hopefully this will replace any missing files or folders an get it working again.

Comment: still happen.never change.please I can't upload picture coz there's so many term to do.