# How do I reset to the default file manager for all folders?

Tags: 12.04, filemanager

I keep getting the `Failed to Execute Default File Manager` for when I try to open files from Firefox. The other error I get is I can't use any shortcuts to get to folders from the panels. I only can use the desktop to get to any folder. Any ideas on how to fix this? I figured I could reset the File Manager. Can this be done? if so, how?

Comment: Run this command: `exo-preferred-applications` and go to `Utilities` tab and in `File Manager` selection list chose your preferred file manager. You would get `Nautilus` if it is installed in your system. Chose that if you want to set it as default and close. Reply what happens..

Comment: @SauravKumar Okay, since I'm running on Xubuntu, I have Thunar installed but no Nautilus. I did what Mitch said to do below and than what you just posted here (Dropbox started working) sta and made Nautilus my default file manager. Everything works now. It seems there probably something wrong with Thunar (the default file manager for Xubuntu). Thanks for the help though. Wish I could give you credit too but I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: It's good to know that your problem is solved..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install nautilus
```

Comment: Thanks, was using Thunar since I have Xubuntu installed.  This installed Nautilus for the first time, made it my default file manager and everything works now.

Comment: Damn. So I realized that I had removed file  `tracker-miner-fs` together with `nautilus` because it was hogging my CPU. Today I could not open files, they kept opening in the next program on the recent list of 'Open With..' menu.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was https://askubuntu.com/users/124963/saurav-kumar answer

> Run this command: exo-preferred-applications and go to Utilities tab
>   and in File Manager selection list chose your preferred file manager.
>   You would get Nautilus if it is installed in your system. Chose that
>   if you want to set it as default and close.

I wanted to set dolphin as my default file manager so installing nautilus isn't the solution.